# Half page printing using dot matrix printer in javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

Now I am working with dot matrix printer using Asp.net client printing.
But i want a half page print. i am using css like  page-break-after:avoid .
But it doesn't stop after print the half page. (working in firefox,not working in IE and chrome)

Comment: add code to the question, there could be many possible solutions, some code would help

Comment: i just build the html dynamically and open it in a popup window, and use dot matrix printer friendly css. no other code.